# Using {%extends var_name%} not being re-evaluated in

Tags: python, django

**EDIT**: *This does not appear to touch jinja.  I was wrong.  Its pure django templates.*

**FIXED**: *Embarrassing: Combination of old django-templated-email and workarounds for broken 1.9 template system.  With new django (v1.11.x) and new lib (v2.2.0) it works fine again.  This codebase started around 1.4.  Not sure how this lib update was missed.  I don't know if django fixed the template loader bug (it couldn't remember dirs to search on the second pass) or if the lib fixed it*

I am using Django for email templating.  Our template uses `{% extends %}` to dynamically derive from a base template depending on the style of email chosen by the user.

It appears that the {extends} is never re-evaluated.  Whichever value was supplied for the `base_template` parameter is always re-used. It feels like the two where textually combined.

- Using `django-templated-email` package (which uses std templates)
- This uses the default DjangoTemplates engine
- I've logged all calls to `cached.Loader` and the base template is never re-requested
- `{% include footer %}` seem to be re-fetched from the loader every time
- `Debug=True|False` results in no change
- I clear the template cache before each call, to no effect

Our email templates look like this:

```
# email/object_created.email
{% extends base_template %}
{% block subject_line %}New Object Created{% endblock %}
{% block html_content %}
    <h2>Hello {{ name }},</h2>
{% endlbock %}

# base_template (email/base/*.email) are like this:
<html>
    ...static html code, different in each base/*.email file...
    {% include 'email/partials/contents-footer.html' %}
</html>
```

Cache Clearing works like this:

```
from django.template import engines
for template in engines.all():
    for loader in template.engine.template_loaders:
        loader.reset()
        for ln in loader.loaders:
            ln.reset()
```

I'm not sure about how Jinja2 actually behaves with {extends} and didn't see anything in the documentation saying this will or will not happen.

We call `send_templated_email` like this:

```
send_templated_mail(
    template_name="object_created",
    template_prefix="email/",
    context=dict(
        # this value changes, but only used(?) the 1st time
        # for each template_name.  different template_names reload it
        base_template="email/base/happy.email",
        name="Sam & Max"
    ),
    recipient_list=[...],
    ...
)
```

This results in a `printf_trace`© of something like what is below.  The output has been shortend to fit better on the screen, but thats about it.

```
django.template.loader.get_template('email/object_created.email')
  uses: <django.DjangoTemplates at 0x108573668>
    .get_template('email/object_created.email') <Engine object at 0x108d7a2e8>
      .find_template('email/object_created.email') <cached.Loader at 0x10b957ef0>
      .find_template('email/base/happy.email') <cached.Loader at 0x10b957ef0>
      .find_template('email/partials/contents-footer.html') <cached.Loader at 0x10b957ef0>
...
django.template.loader.get_template('email/object_created.email')
  uses: <django.DjangoTemplates at 0x108573668>
    .get_template('email/object_created.email') <Engine object at 0x108d7a2e8>
      .find_template('email/object_created.email') <cached.Loader at 0x10b957ef0>
      .find_template('email/partials/contents-footer.html') <cached.Loader at 0x10b957ef0>
```

Comment: Can you include the part of the code when you actually use the template loader ? `send_templated_email` maybe ?

Comment: Sure.  Its just that there are so many levels between that and the actual template loading that it didn't seem relevant.  In the end its just a DjangoTemplate

Comment: I understand. Do you have the `DEBUG` option set to `True` ? Or did you try to set it to `False` ? Maybe a cached problem: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader. If this cache is active, it might explain why your parent template is never fetched again. Since the cache key is set to the template name itself: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loaders/cached.py#L68

Comment: After reading your edits, it seems my assumption was correct. Django use the `extends` only once. Once it's rendered (and cached), he use the cached version (with the `extends` already rendered).

Comment: Changing `debug` has no effect on this.  I should have noted that.  Also, I get a reference to all the loaders and do a .reset() which should clear their caches, but it also doesn't help.

Comment: Also, the footer file is *always* fetched with every template, cached or not.  But the base template is not.  The cache clearing gets references to the exact same objects (see the references there)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159544/discussion-between-clement-denoix-and-andrew-backer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mea culpa, and a little embarrassing. The issue is fixed in newer versions of `django-templated-email` and `django`.  I put a lot of time into tracking it down, which was wasted.

In short, django 1.9 had an issue where the templates would be re-evaluated each time, but the loader would forget the search directories when dealing with {extends} nodes, maybe more.  This lead to a workaround in a custom patch (maybe cribbed from their tracker?) and a custom package in our pypi.  Unfortunately I used the same name as the original, so `pip list --outdated` didn't show it.

I'm not sure at what level the issue was resolved.  I imagine it was at the `django` level rather than in `django-templated-email` but I'm a bit to tired of staring at all this code to look further.

Moral of the story is: **always** check your dependencies, and re-evaluate when a new django version is out.  Templated email didn't release, so we had to package the proposed fix as part of it ourselves and deploy it.